# Getting error while calling WCF, soap object as a parameter

Tags: android, web-services, wcf, soap, android-ksoap2

Getting ‘can not serialize’ error while calling WCF webservice with SoapObject as a parameter. Working fine when sending SoapObject  as a string to the parameter while testing other services.

I am kind of lost now. Any android killer there.

CODE:

```
final String URL ="http://192.168.1.8:9608/WcfServiceShreeHari/Service1.svc";
 final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";

 final String METHOD = "GetName";
 final String ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetName";


String resp = "";
    try {

        JSONArray array=null; 
        JSONObject object=null;
        JSONObject mainObject = null;


        object=new JSONObject();
        mainObject=new JSONObject();
        array=new JSONArray();


        mainObject.put("UserName", "ss");
        mainObject.put("Token", "tokxd43cxen");


       SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
       envelope.dotNet=true;
       SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD);
       request.addProperty("request", mainObject);
       envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
       HttpTransportSE aht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
           try {
             aht.call( ACTION, envelope);
           } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
             resp = e.getMessage();
           } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
             resp = e.getMessage();
         }

       if (envelope.bodyIn != null) {

         //SoapPrimitive resultSOAP = (SoapPrimitive) ((SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn).getProperty(0);
        //  SoapPrimitive resultSOAP = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
            resp = envelope.getResponse().toString();
       }
     } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
       resp = e.getMessage();
     }

    return resp;
```

ERROR:

```
06-18 19:11:01.839: W/System.err(7682): java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot serialize: {"UserName":"ss","Token":"tokxd43cxen"}
06-18 19:11:01.844: W/System.err(7682):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeElement(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:708)
06-18 19:11:01.844: W/System.err(7682):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeProperty(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:692)
06-18 19:11:01.844: W/System.err(7682):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeObjectBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:661)
06-18 19:11:01.844: W/System.err(7682):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeObjectBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:645)
06-18 19:11:01.844: W/System.err(7682):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeElement(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:702)
06-18 19:11:01.844: W/System.err(7682):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:618)
06-18 19:11:01.844: W/System.err(7682):     at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.write(SoapEnvelope.java:198)
06-18 19:11:01.844: W/System.err(7682):     at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.createRequestData(Transport.java:107)
06-18 19:11:01.849: W/System.err(7682):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:119)
06-18 19:11:01.849: W/System.err(7682):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:95)
06-18 19:11:01.849: W/System.err(7682):     at com.example.srihari.LogIn$webService.webServiceCall(LogIn.java:903)
06-18 19:11:01.849: W/System.err(7682):     at com.example.srihari.LogIn$webService.doInBackground(LogIn.java:398)
06-18 19:11:01.849: W/System.err(7682):     at com.example.srihari.LogIn$webService.doInBackground(LogIn.java:1)
06-18 19:11:01.849: W/System.err(7682):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-18 19:11:01.849: W/System.err(7682):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
06-18 19:11:01.849: W/System.err(7682):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
06-18 19:11:01.849: W/System.err(7682):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
06-18 19:11:01.854: W/System.err(7682):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
06-18 19:11:01.854: W/System.err(7682):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
06-18 19:11:01.854: W/System.err(7682):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

WEB METHOD:

```
public string ImportOrders(Request request) 
        {

            var inputObj = request.OrderList;

            long UserID = GetUserID(request.UserName, request.Token);
            if (UserID == 0)
            {
                service_error.longMessage = "Error code:100. Validation Failed.Please send proper credentials.";

                                return CreateResponseXML2("Error", service_error.longMessage);
            }
            CommonUtilities.UserId = UserID;
            CommonUtilities.OrderTotal = inputObj.Count.ToString();
            CommonUtilities.OrderSuccess = "";
            CommonUtilities.OrderFailure = "";
            CommonUtilities.OrderUpdated = "";
            CommonUtilities.OrderAdded = "";
            CommonUtilities.AddedCustomer = "";

            #region set imported orders    

            foreach (var inputOrder in inputObj)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputOrder.OrderUniqueId) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputOrder.TabID))
                {
                    CommonUtilities.OrderErr(inputOrder.OrderUniqueId, "OrderUniqueId or TabID Not Exists");
                    continue;
                }
                if (inputOrder.ItemList.Count == 0)
                {
                    CommonUtilities.OrderErr(inputOrder.OrderUniqueId, "ItemList Not provided");
                    continue;
                }
                int ErrCount = 0; string ErrProdusts = ""; int itemno = 0; string ProductAttr = ""; int ProductAttrErrCount = 0;
                string AttrName = ""; string ErrProdustsAll = "";
                using (Data.ShreeHariWebEntities ent = new Data.ShreeHariWebEntities())
                {                    
                    foreach (var item in inputOrder.ItemList)
                    {
                        itemno++;
                        ProductAttr = "";
                        ProductAttrErrCount = 0;
                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.ModelNumber) || item.Category <=0 || string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Size) || item.UnitPrice <= 0 || item.Quantity <= 0)
                        {
                            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.ModelNumber))
                            {
                                AttrName = "ModelNumber";
                                ProductAttr += string.IsNullOrEmpty(ProductAttr) ? AttrName : ", " + AttrName;
                                ErrCount++;
                                ProductAttrErrCount++;
                            }
                            if (item.Category <= 0)
                            {
                                AttrName = "Catagory";
                                ProductAttr += string.IsNullOrEmpty(ProductAttr) ? AttrName : ", " + AttrName;
                                ErrCount++;
                                ProductAttrErrCount++;
                            }
                           if (item.UnitPrice <= 0)
                            {
                                AttrName = "UnitPrice";
                                ProductAttr += string.IsNullOrEmpty(ProductAttr) ? AttrName : ", " + AttrName;
                                ErrCount++;
                                ProductAttrErrCount++;
                            }
                            if (item.Quantity <=0)
                            {
                                AttrName = "Qunatity";
                                ProductAttr += string.IsNullOrEmpty(ProductAttr) ? AttrName : ", " + AttrName;
                                ErrCount++;
                                ProductAttrErrCount++;
                            }
                            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Size))
                            {
                                AttrName = "Size";
                                ProductAttr += string.IsNullOrEmpty(ProductAttr) ? AttrName : ", " + AttrName;
                                ErrCount++;
                                ProductAttrErrCount++;
                            }
                            if (ProductAttrErrCount != 0)
                                ErrProdusts = "Missing Attributes " + ProductAttr;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var prod = (from p in ent.Products
                                        where p.ModelNumber == item.ModelNumber && p.Size == item.Size
                                            && p.Category == item.Category && p.Color == item.Color
                                        select p
                                    ).FirstOrDefault();
                            if (prod == null)
                            {
                                AttrName = "Not Exists";
                                                                ErrCount++;
                                ErrProdusts = AttrName;
                                ProductAttrErrCount++;
                            }

                        }
                        if (ProductAttrErrCount != 0)
                            ErrProdustsAll += " ##Item-" + itemno.ToString() + " " + ErrProdusts;

                    }
                }
                if (ErrCount != 0)
                {
                    CommonUtilities.OrderErr(inputOrder.OrderUniqueId, ErrProdustsAll);
                    continue;
                }

                CommonUtilities.OrderValidate = "";
                OrderData_Validation(inputOrder);

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(CommonUtilities.OrderValidate))
                {
                    CommonUtilities.OrderErr(inputOrder.OrderUniqueId,service_error.longMessage);
                    continue;
                }


                if (inputOrder.OrderTotal == 0)
                {
                    decimal orderTotal = 0;
                    foreach (var item in inputOrder.ItemList)
                    {
                        orderTotal += item.UnitPrice * (decimal)item.Quantity;
                    }
                    inputOrder.OrderTotal = orderTotal + inputOrder.ShippingPaid + inputOrder.TaxAmount;
                }

                Order op = new Order();

                using (Data.ShreeHariWebEntities ent1 = new Data.ShreeHariWebEntities())
                {
                    op = (from odr in ent1.Orders
                          where odr.OrderNumber == inputOrder.OrderNumber
                            && odr.OrderUniqueId == inputOrder.OrderUniqueId
                          select odr).FirstOrDefault();
                }

                if (op == null)
                {
                    oh.AddOrder(inputOrder, new Result());
                }
                else
                {
                    Result r = new Result();
                    inputOrder.OrderID = op.OrderID;
                    inputOrder.StoreID = op.StoreID;

                    bool UpdateSuccessfull = oh.UpdateManualOrder(inputOrder,r);
                    if (UpdateSuccessfull)
                    {
                        CommonUtilities.OrderUp(inputOrder.OrderUniqueId);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        CommonUtilities.OrderErr(inputOrder.OrderUniqueId,"<![CDATA["+r.ErrorMessage+"]]>");
                    }
                }
            }

            #endregion

            string msg = "<TotalOrder>" + CommonUtilities.OrderTotal + "</TotalOrder>";
                            msg = msg + "<FailedOrders>" + CommonUtilities.OrderFailure + "</FailedOrders>";

                msg = msg + "<AddedOrder>" + CommonUtilities.OrderAdded + "</AddedOrder>";
                msg = msg + "<UpdatedOrder>" + CommonUtilities.OrderUpdated + "</UpdatedOrder>";
                msg = msg + "<Customers>" + CommonUtilities.AddedCustomer + "</Customers>";
            return CreateResponseXML2("Success", msg);

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
       envelope.dotNet=true;
       SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD);
       request.addProperty("request", mainObject.toString());
       envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
```

OR, Use this

```
        // Property Name
        PropertyInfo piName = new PropertyInfo();
        piName.setName("sName");
        piName.setValue("Value Here");
        piName.setType(JSONObject.class);
        request.addProperty(piName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way,

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD);
request.addProperty("UserName", "ss");
request.addProperty("Token", "tokxd43cxen");
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
envelope.implicitTypes = false;
envelope.dotNet = true;
```

May be this will help you.